# Qt 5.5 on fedora serialport module not found

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm using fedora 23.
Using QT Creator with Qt 5.5.0 installed
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.5.0 in /usr/lib

When I type in "QT += serialport" Qt Creator throws the message "Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: serialport"
I thought serialport is included since version 5.1.

Kit setting in Qt Creator is set to qmake-qt5 with qt 5.5

Comment: I don't use Fedora, but you might want to install the qt5-qtserialport-devel package.

Comment: This was the solution!

Answer (score 2):

```
yum install qt5-qtserialport-devel
```

solved the problem. Thanks to tux3 for the solution!

Comment: For ubuntu users: sudo apt-get install libqt5serialport5 libqt5serialport5-dev

Comment: @basti-an, you may mark your own answer as the accepted answer to the clearly indicate to the public that this answer solves your question.